# Python printing before function call returns?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
ls = get_details(urls)
print "wtf..."
print "wtf..."
print "wtf..."
```

`get_details()` is doing a bit of screenscraping with xpath, it returns/generates a generator of about 200 lists containing ~10 pieces of profile information.

Why is it executing the print statements before the function returns...??? I have quadruple checked it for silly indent errors etc...

EDIT: I'm sorry folks I can't post the code. But a print statement on line 2 executing before the function on line 1 returns... is new to me.

FIX: OK so, apparently I had to "exhaust" the generator after I returned it... didnt know that, what else don't I know about generators ^.^

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generator need to be exhausted before it return.

```
gen = get_details(urls)
for x in gen:
    # do something with x
print "wtf..."
print "wtf..."
print "wtf..."
```

Comment: @Devansh, Reading [Generator - Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) will be helpful. If you're unfamiliar with iterator, read [Iterator - Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) first.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it executing the print statements before the function return the value.
Do

```
ls = get_details(urls)
print ls
print "wtf..."
```

and post the answer.

Comment: Because I'm doing prints in the get_details function :)

Comment: Can you post more details so that we can run the program and check for possible errors?

Comment: Sorry Devansh, can't post the code for this one. Thanks for trying to help me out guys, hopefully I can return the favour one day :)